# Using JQuery to sum integers within table, then find the largest sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, parseint

I have a large HTML table that is updated automatically every 24 hours with new data. the 5th column contains multiple numbers in each row separated by a line break, each containing class `.remaining-detail`. I'm looking to add the numbers from each row, and then find which row contains the largest sum from column 5.

```
<table>
<tr class="row-3 odd">
    <td class="column-1 ">ID</td><br><br><td class="column-2 ">                            <a href="*" class="ex" title="Big Money">Name</a><br>

<br><td class="column ">                            <a href="*" class="ex" title="Big Money">Area</a><br>
                            <br>
                            </td><td class="column-3 ">$5</td><td class="column-4 ">                            <div class="remaining-detail">$100,000.00</div>
                            <div class="remaining-detail">$10,000.00</div>
                            <div class="remaining-detail">$1,000.00</div>

                            <div class="remaining-detail">$500.00</div>
                            <div class="remaining-detail">$400.00</div>
                            <div class="remaining-detail">$100.00</div><br><br>
                            </td><td class="column-5 ">                            <div class="remaining-detail">1</div><br>
                            <div class="remaining-detail">0</div><br>
                            <div class="remaining-detail">36</div><br>

                            <div class="remaining-detail">64</div><br>
                            <div class="remaining-detail">100</div><br>
                            <div class="remaining-detail">972</div><br>
                            </td>
</tr></table>
<br>
```

I am adding these numbers like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var sum = 0;

$('.row-2 .column-5 .remaining-detail').each(function () {
sum += parseInt($(this).html().replace(',',''));
});
$('#sum2').text(sum);
});
```

This works for a single instance. How would I go about doing this for `.ROW N .column-5 .remaining-detail` and then find the row with the largest sum?

Here is a fiddle with what I have right now: http://jsfiddle.net/3LHb8/

Comment: Please paste your html ..

Comment: I added a fiddle with what I have right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with two nested `.each()` loops. Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var sums = [];

    $('tbody tr').each(function() {
        var rowSum = 0;
        $(this).find('.remaining-detail').each(function () {
            rowSum += parseInt($(this).html().replace(',',''));
        });
        sums.push(rowSum);
    });

    $('#sum2').text("Biggest sum is in row " + (1 + sums.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, sums))));

});
```

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seiseises/3LHb8/2/). I'm storing the sums of each row and then printing the row with the highest sum, but you can do whatever variation you need. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hoefully this is what you are looking for

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var maxsum = 0;


        $(".column-5").each(function(){
            alert('inside');
            var coloumnSum = 0;
            $(this).find(".remaining-detail").each(function(){          
                coloumnSum = coloumnSum + parseInt($(this).html(), 10);
            });
            if(maxsum < coloumnSum){
                maxsum = coloumnSum;
            }
        });
    alert(maxsum);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to tell with no html... Can you share at least 2 rows of your html table and we can help.

oh well, you can try something like this:

```
var sum = 0;
var sum2 = 0;
var trIndex = 0;
$('.row-2 .column-5').each(function () {
    sum = 0;
    $(this').find('.remaining-detail').each(function () {
        sum += parseInt($(this).html().replace(',',''));
        });
        if (sum > sum2)
        {
            sum2 = sum;
            trIndex = $(this).parents('tr').index();
        }
    });
}

alert('row='+trIndex+' sum='+sum2);
$('tr').eq(trIndex-1).css('background-color','#ff0000');
```

EDIT

Thanks for sharing some html, let us know if the example code we provide works for you :)